# Apply NavigationBar style to all Navigation Bars in MonoTouch?

Tags: iphone, ios, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Currently, I am using the following code repeated throughout my application since apparently you aren't supposed to subclass UINavigationController (correct me if I am wrong):

```
var galleryNavigation = new UINavigationController(galleryDialog);

galleryNavigation.NavigationBar.TintColor = UIColor.FromRGB (33, 114, 131);
galleryNavigation.NavigationBar.Alpha = 0.7f;
galleryNavigation.NavigationBar.Translucent = true;
```

I want to define these styles (TintColor, Alpha, etc.) once and reuse them.  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to set some properties than you can make a method in your AppDelegate or Some shared Class call it from each view controller like

```
-(void)setNavigation:(UIViewController*)vc
{
   //set properties here

}
```

otherwise if you want more customization than a good option will be to make a subclass of **UINavigationBar** get inherit it in each view controller as

```
// Get our custom nav bar
    MyNavigationBar* customNavigationBar =  (MyNavigationBar*)self.navigationController.navigationBar;    
    // Set the nav bar's properties as you want like i have set its background image as
    [customNavigationBar setBackgroundWith:[UIImage imageNamed:ImgNavBarBackground]];
```

Comment: I think I am looking for something similar to the subclassing of UINavigationBar, but like my original question states, I'm looking for a MonoTouch solution.  Thanks.

Comment: Oh sorry I haven't seen MonoTouch and also not much aware of it but the correct way will be subclassing UINavigationBar.